# Configure CSS for simple webpage with GWT

Tags: java, css, gwt

i try to create a very simple web page with GWT. My actually web page looks like this:

```
--------------------------------
|          (menu fix)  LoginBtn|
|                              |
|           Menu bar           |
|                              |
--------------------------------
```

CSS File:

```
.menu_fix {
width: 100%;
height: 10%;
margin-top: -150px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 0;
margin: auto;
margin-left: -50%;}

.loginBtn {
float: right; }

.menubar {
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 135px;
width: 20%;
left: 150px; }
```

Java File:

```
public StartViewImpl() {
    VerticalPanel mainPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    mainPanel.add(createHeader());
    mainPanel.add(createMenuBar());

    Image widget = new Image("cat.jpg");
    widget.setPixelSize(400,400);
    widget.setStyleName("????");

    mainPanel.add(widget);
    handlerList = new HashMap<Widget, HandlerRegistration>();
    initWidget(mainPanel);
}

private FlowPanel createHeader() {
    FlowPanel fixHeaderPanel = new FlowPanel();
    fixHeaderPanel.setStyleName("menu_fix");
    Button loginBtn = new Button("Login");
    loginBtn.addStyleName("loginBtn");
    ...
    return fixHeaderPanel;
}

private HorizontalPanel createMenuBar() {
    menuPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
    menuPanel.addStyleName("menubar");
    ...
    return menuPanel;
}
```

In constructor `StartViewImpl` i try to add a image. What is the correct css style to add the image to center of the web page? The Image should display under the menu bar. Have GWT sample templates? I have no idea how to use correctly css styles in gwt projects.

Best regards, Chris

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
.image {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

widget.setStyleName("image");
```

Or, you can do it this way:

```
mainPanel.setCellHorizontalAlignment(widget, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
```

Comment: hey, i know how to connect css files in gwt...but i asks for a css style... Thank you for the link, i will read the linked site.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem statement:**

Add the image to center of the web page. The Image should display under the menu bar.

**Solution:**

Try this code.

Java:

```
widget.setStyleName("img");
```

CSS:

```
.img{
   margin-left: 50%;
   margin-top: 135px;
}
```